# Core Data - Validate Correctness of Predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitextfield, nspredicate

I am trying to build a user interface for querying core data tables and list results in a tabular form. As part of the requirement, I need to use a UITextField to capture predicate that will be supplied to an NSPredicate. Now considering the fact that this feature will be used not just by developers, but others who are not well versed in predicate syntax, an erroneous predicate may be supplied. This would lead to application crash. How can I validate the correctness of the expression before I execute request?

Comment: I don't think you can.  You shouldn't be exposing predicate syntax to non-developers.  Come up with a DSL which you can parse and validate.

Comment: Followup: You can actually check each predicate's parts and check them against your model.  It would be a lot of work, but it should be doable if your model is simple.  At the end, predicates are collections of `NSExpression` objects.  See the section *Getting Information About an Expression* in the class reference for `NSExpression`.

Comment: I'm writing this as a comment because it doesn't directly answer your question.   I'm with @Avi that the predicate string shouldn't be exposed to the user.   Instead, what I suggest you do is build a query builder interface.   Each expression consists of [field] [operator] [value].  You can allow more than one expression to be chained together by [and|or].   [operator] can be '=', '>', '<', etc. etc.   This way you have more control over the inputs and can validate each expression before building the actual predicate string out of the combined expression.

Comment: I'd agree with @jp2g. I'd make a form like that can add or/and (for combine predicate), and a way to give the key, the operator and the value in a user friendly way (not how you coded it with your var names) but with friendly names. You may also want to save the predicates if they are complex in order to avoid the user to redo them from scratch.

Comment: I have made a query builder interface what @jp2g has suggested, to solve problem. Thanks all for your suggestions!